# Kotlin List vs java.util.List generic type inside Java code

Tags: java, kotlin, dagger-2

I'm stuck with strange behavior while migrating my project to kotlin.

It's occurred while i tried to generate dagger injectors. The problem in java or dagger, someone can't resolve kotlin List from generic type

Example:

```kotlin
interface CacheEntity<Result> {
  fun onResult(result: Result)
  fun getUpdatableData(): Observable<Result>
}
```

```kotlin
class CacheRepository< Result, Entity:CacheEntity<Result> >(
  val entity: Entity) {

   // do some operations with Entity
   fun doSome() {
     entity.getUpdatableData()
     entity.onResult(...)
   }
}
```

```kotlin
class UserRepository: CacheEntity<User> {
  override fun onResult(result: User) {}
  override fun getUpdatableData(): Observable<User> {}
}
```

Now if i'm tring to create cached user repository instance, everything it's ok
Then this code translates to application using dagger injections

```kotlin
val cachedUserRepo = CacheRepository<User, UserRepository>(UserRepository())
```

But! If i'm trying to result the list of data

```kotlin
class OrdersRepository: CacheEntity<List<Order>> {
  // overrides CacheEntity methods
}

val cachedOrdersRepo = CacheRepository<List<Order>, OrdersRepository>(OrdersRepository())
```

Everything is fine, but not in dagger-generated java code:
**MyComponent.java**

```java
private CacheRepository<List<Order>, OrdersRepository> cachedOrdersRepository;
```

error while building

```
error: type argument OrdersRepository is not within bounds of type-variable Entity
  private Provider<CachedRepository<List<Order>, OrdersRepository>> cachedOrdersRepository;
                                                              ^
  where Entity,Result are type-variables:
    Entity extends CacheEntity<Result> declared in class CacheRepository
    Result extends Object declared in class CacheRepository
```

Java code contains **java.util.List** which is incompatible with **kotlin.collections.List**,
but dagger module class written in kotlin and returns valid kotlin **kotlin.collections.List**

```kotlin
@Module
object RepoModule {
  @JvmStatic
  @Provides
  fun provideCacheOrdersRepository(): CacheRepository<List<Order>, OrdersRepository> {
    return CacheRepository(OrdersRepository())
  }

}
```

So, how to solve this? I have a couple ideas, but i don't like this:

- Rewrite dagger module in java, it worked before i converted to kotlin
- Forced using **java.util.List**, but it's a very bad idea

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is related to the bytecode conversion of a Kotlin list and the wildcards added in the signature, making it a `java.util.List<? extends T>` instead of a `java.lang.List<T>`.

To fix it without switching to an invariant type (e.g. `MutableList`) you should use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` on the the `List` type:

**e.g.**

```kotlin
class OrdersRepository: CacheEntity<List<@JvmSuppressWildcards Order>>
```

I've added just one fragment of your full code, you should check your list usages and use `@JvmSuppressWildcards` on them.

Comment: Wildcards are already suppressed in `provideCacheOrdersRepository`.  However, they aren't suppressed in the declaration of `OrdersRepository`, and this mismatch causes the issue.

Comment: @Nitrodon Yes, you are right! I'm updating the sample code fragment, thanks!

Comment: `MutableList` is invariant, not contravariant.

Comment: @Alexey Romanov What a shame, I swapped the words in my mind. Correcting it.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i've found quick solution: Using `MutableList<T>` solves this problem, and it seams compatible with `java.util.List<T>` by unknown reason.